# Python Polars Read CSV with header names

Tags: csv, python-polars

In pandas, one can specify the names of a csv with:

```py
pd.read_csv(filename, names = [ 'city', 'pop' ])
```

How does on do so in Python `polars`?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the columns to read using the `columns` parameter in `read_csv`. If you want to rename, there is also the parameter `new_columns`, which accepts a list of column names that you will assign.

See also the reference guide: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv.